# C++, error invalid conversion from `int*' to `int'

Tags: c++

I have the following C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
}
int findH(int positionH[]){
    return positionH;         //error happens here.
}
```

The compiler throws an error:

```
invalid conversion from `int*' to `int'
```

What does this error mean?

Comment: Check the return type of the `findH` again, and compare to what it actually returns and what you try to assign the return value to.

Comment: findH returns and int and you have int bla[2]

Comment: "Apparently in the findH function, a 2 dimensional array positionH is created..?" -- No, that's not what the error message says, and I don't see how you have come to that conclusion.

Comment: Look good at the type of positionH. What do the [] mean?

Comment: @user1876088: The error means exactly what it says it mean. There's really nothing to add here. `positionH` is an `int *`. The function is declared as returning `int`. So, your `return positionH` attempts to convert `int *` to `int`, which is illegal. The real question here is what your code is supposed to mean. What did you try to achieve by that function?

Answer (score 6):

`positionH[]` is an array, and its return type is `int`.

The compiler will not let you do that.  Either make the parameter an int:

```
int findH(int positionH){
    return positionH;        
}
```

Or make the return type a pointer to an int:

```
int* findH(int positionH[]){
    return positionH;        
}
```

Or convert the array to an integer before return:

```
int findH(int positionH[]){
    return positionH[0];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This line is invalid C++ (and invalid C too, which your code appears to be written in):

```
int bla[2] = findH(field, positionH);
```

bla is an array of 2 elements and cannot be initialised that way. findH returns int.

Answer (score 2):

This error is coming while you are trying to do:

```
int *p =10;
```

that means you are assigning `int` value to pointertoint `*p` .

But pointer is storing address that means `*p` is taking `10` as address.

So 
just do:

```
int i=10;
int *p=&i;
```

or

```
p=&i;
```

it will not give any error.

Answer (score 0):

The error was caused because you returned a pointer and the compiler is expecting a int.

There is a very BIG difference between int * and int.

Also why are you returning positionH, arrays are passed by reference, there is no need to return it.

Better code would be

```
void option1(char** field, int[])   
   {
     int  findH(char **, int[]); 
     int positionH[2];
    findH(field, positionH);
      //positionH passed by reference, no need to return it
    }

void  findH(char **field, int positionH[])
{
    for(int n = 0;n < 14 ; n++)
    {
        for(int m = 0; m < 14; m++)
        {
                   if(field[m][n] == 'H')
                   {

                   positionH[0] = n;
                   positionH[1] = m;

        }
         }
    }

}
```

Comment: THanks a lot! this really was an eye opener for me, that there is no need to return the value.

Comment: @user1876088, Learn more about `pass by reference` and `pass by values`, it would help you go a long way in helping you prevent future errors.

Comment: @DesertIce, you are mistaken -- `positionH` is not passed by reference here.